# A question about linear independence of functions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$ be a linear independent set of functions over the open interval $I$. In addition, suppose that $g$ is a continuous function on $I,$ which is not identically zero.

If $g(x)\neq0$ for all $x\in I$, then it is easy to prove that
$\{gf_1,\ldots,gf_n\}$ is linearly independent as well. Is the following generalization true?

**If $g$ vanishes for some finite number of values, then  $\{gf_1,\ldots,gf_n\}$ is linearly independent as well.**

Comment: Let the $f_i$ be equal except at some finite set of inputs, let $g$ be zero at those inputs.

Comment: Any thoughts on my comment?

Comment: thanks Garry. What if the $f_i$ ang $g$ are smooth ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answers the modified question in the comments, where we assume the $f_i$ and $g$ are smooth.

Suppose $\sum_ia_igf_i$ is identically zero (on the open, nonempty interval, $I$). Then $(g)\left(\sum_ia_if_i\right)$ is identically zero. But $g$ has only finitely many zeros (by hypothesis), so $\sum_ia_if_i$ must be zero at all but finitely many points of $I$. But the sum is continuous, so it must be identically zero. But the $f_i$ are linearly independent (by hypothesis), so the $a_i$ must all be zero. Therefore, the $gf_i$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks Garry. Can we droop the smoothness for something less ?

Comment: That's *Gerry*. You need for it to be impossible for there to be a finite, nonzero number of zeros. I don't see how to do that without continuity.

Comment: But there are smooth functions with infinite number of zeros.  For example, the function $f$ such that $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$, is smooth with infinite number of zeros.

Comment: Oops, I meant a finite nonzero number of *nonzeros*. You need it to be impossible for the linear combination to be zero everywhere except at a finite, nonzero number of places.